# Android Stuido ошибка компиляции

Tags: android-studio

Создал новый проект, ничего не добавлял, происходила сборка и выкинуло ошибку:

```
D:\Project\Hamster\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

файл color выглядит так:

```
include ':app'
```

Пробовал добавить что-то наподобие вот такого:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    </resources>
```

Кидает ошибку:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\Project\Hamster\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\Danilshik\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\feb1b0106ecb01d03bc5d06dff1df1c9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\Project\Hamster\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\Project\Hamster\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Пробовал rebuild, clean, make project - **не помогло**

Пробовал удалить кеш C:\Users\.gradle\caches - **не помогло**

Пробовал создать новый проект - **не помогло**

Пробовал создать проект в другое место - **не помогло**

Пробовал занова поставить Android Studio - **не помогло**

Comment: _colors.xml_ в виде нормальной xml-ки, видимо, работает. Насчет _ic_launcher_round.xml_ - может, он в UTF-8, а не "UTF-8 без BOM"? Как он вообще у вас выглядит - там валидная xml-ка?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким образом: удалил все xml из res, так как они в конце файла были не в той кодировке. После совершил успешную компиляцию. Удалил проект и создал занова чтобы xml появились занова